# 2nd parameter for preparedStatement java - ORDER BY -syntax error

Tags: java, prepared-statement

My preparedStatement works fine until I start adding a second ? parameter into the SQL code to make the ORDER BY more flexible.

If I hardcode the ? to for example ASC it works fine, so I'm not sure why the  "queryType.setString(2, orderType);" causes this trouble in the scenario below.

Error:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "?": syntax error)

Important part of the code:

```
public static final String QUERY_ITEMS_AFTER_TYPE =
            "SELECT " + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + COLUMN_EXISTING_QUANTITY + ',' +
            COLUMN_RECOMMENDED_STOCK + " FROM " + TABLE_STOCKITEMS + " WHERE " +
            COLUMN_STORED_TYPES + " = ? ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ?";
```

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
 queryType = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY_ITEMS_AFTER_TYPE);`

```
public List<StockItem> queryTypeList (String storeType, String orderType) {
    try {
        queryType.setString(1, storeType);
        queryType.setString(2, orderType);
        ResultSet results = queryType.executeQuery();

        List<StockItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        while (results.next()) {
            StockItem item = new StockItem();              
            item.setName(results.getString(INDEX_STOCKITEMS_NAME));
            item.addItemQuantity(results.getInt(COLUMN_EXISTING_QUANTITY));
            item.setRecommendedStock(results.getInt(INDEX_STOCKITEMS_RECOMMENDED_STOCK));
            items.add(item);
        }
        return items;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ops: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

*UPDATE:*

What I didn't realize is that the placeholder from the preparedStatement are actually only for **column values** and therefor won't work if I want to use them for the ORDER BY part.

Using a stringFormat was my solution to fix this problem now.

```
public static final String QUERY_ITEMS_AFTER_TYPE =
    "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + ',' + COLUMN_NAME + ',' + COLUMN_EXISTING_QUANTITY + ',' +
            COLUMN_RECOMMENDED_STOCK + " FROM " + TABLE_STOCKITEMS + " WHERE " +
            COLUMN_STORED_TYPES + " = ? ORDER BY " + COLUMN_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE %s";
```

important code bit:

```
public List<StockItem> queryTypeList (String storeType,int sortOrder ) {
    try {
        .....
        String sqlFormat = String.format(QUERY_ITEMS_AFTER_TYPE, orderType);
        queryType = conn.prepareStatement(sqlFormat);

        queryType.setString(1, storeType);
        ResultSet results = queryType.executeQuery();
```

Comment: You can't bind a parameter like that. PreparedStatement is used to compile a statement into a reusable form on the database. And you can't stick bind parameters just anywhere. For example, you can't put one at `COLLATE NOCASE ?`

Comment: `?` markers can only replace **values**, e.g. numbers (`42`) and strings (`'Hello'`)